# activateConstraints isn't updating the frame as opposed to addConstraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

iOS 8 states UIView's addConstraints is deprecated, and should use NSLayoutConstraints +activateConstraints. So I did a quick test but things are not working for the new method.

From viewdidload or viewdidappear:

Works(The label resizes):

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelLeft);

NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                        constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_labelLeft(100)]"
                        options:0
                        metrics:nil
                        views:views];

NSArray *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                       constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[_labelLeft(100)]"
                       options:0
                       metrics:nil
                       views:views];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
[self.view addConstraints:constraint];
```

Doesn't Work

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelLeft);

NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                        constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_labelLeft(100)]"
                        options:0
                        metrics:nil
                        views:views];

NSArray *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                       constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[_labelLeft(100)]"
                       options:0
                       metrics:nil
                       views:views];


[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:constraint];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:constraints];
```

Anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: addConstraints: is not depreciated as far as I can tell (looking at the class reference published this January). Where did you see this information?

Comment: If you go into the definition of addConstraints it says.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about that in the reference that I get from Xcode, or in the one I get off the web (which was published by Apple on 1/24/15). How are you accessing the UIView class reference document?

Comment: I think that is pretty irrelevant, either is deprecated or not. I just want to know why this method isn't working.

Comment: Your code does work for me when I try it. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What do you see in your UI?

Comment: The second one does not apply the frame size change to the label

Comment: How are the old constraints added? In code or IB? Are you removing, or deactivating those?

Comment: Here was initially none

Comment: Very weird, how did you get it to work?